# I want cin to read until '\n' but I cannot use getline

Tags: c++, string, io, newline, cin

I have a text file in the following format:

```
info
data1 data2
info
data1 data2 data3 data4...
```

The problem is: the count (and length) of the data may be very large and cause run-time problems when `getline()` is used. So I cannot read the entire line into a `std::string`. I tried the following:

```
for(int i=0; i<SOME_CONSTANT ; i++){
    string info, data;

    cin >> info;

    while(cin.peek() != '\n' && cin >> data){
         // do stuff with data
    }
}
```

However `cin.peek()` did not do the trick. The info is read into data in the while loop and program messes things up. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try `std::string::max_size` as second parameter for `std::istream::getline`?

Comment: How would the size of the data be an issue? How long are the lines?

Comment: up to 150.000 characters

Comment: 150,000 characters are just about 150 KiB, so what kind of "run-time problems" does this cause? What is your `std::string::max_size`?

Comment: Actually, I'm bounded by a system I don't know (programming contest, all we know about data are the boundaries). However, I tried to print the size of a line read from my text file, which was 120.000 characters long and the program output nothing for that line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try reading character by character.

```
char ch;
data = "";
cin >> std::noskipws;
while( cin >> ch && ch != '\n' ) {
  if ( ch == " " ) {
    // do stuff with data
    data = "";
    continue;
  }
  data += ch;
}
cin >> std::skipws;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`std::istream::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) instead of `std::getline`. You can choose your buffer size and delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but here is my simpler solution to this question. Just use `do-while`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define SOME_CONSTANT 3

int main() {
    for(int i = 0; i < SOME_CONSTANT ; i++) {
        std::string info, data;

        std::cin >> info;

        do {
            std::cin >> data;
        } while(std::cin.peek() != '\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```